# Jest mock localStorage methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, jestjs

I would like to mock localStorage methods in jest for error simulation. I have localstorage getter and setter methods defined in utility.js. I would like to mock `localStorage.setItem` to throw an error when `utility.setItem` is called.

```
//file: utility.js
export default {
  getItem(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  },
  setItem(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
};
```

In jest,

```
test('throw error', () => {
  localStorage.setItem = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log(" called ");
    throw new Error('ERROR');
  });

  utility.setItem('123', 'value');
});
```

However `localStorage.setItem` mock is never getting called. I have also tried doing

```
window.localStorage.setItem = jest.genMockFunction(()=>{console.log(" Mock Called")});
global.localStorage.setItem = jest.fn(()=>{console.log(" Mock Called")});
```

Comment: What is localStorage you're referring? There's no LS global in Node. And Jest (JSDOM) doesn't add it, afaik. I would expect this code to cause an error because of that.

Comment: DOM localStorage, I upon calling `utility.setItem` i can set the value but instead i want to handle the `sad` case doing mock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This goes inline with what Andreas suggested in the answer, but i was able to mock it using [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) interface. I did something like this,

In jest,

```
test('throw error', () => {
  Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log(" called "); // <-- was called 
    throw new Error('ERROR');
  });

  utility.setItem('123', 'value');
});
```

Also this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6858#issuecomment-413677180) discussion was helpful.

Comment: i tried this but return `ReferenceError: Storage is not defined`

Answer (score 24):

`jest.spyOn(window.localStorage.__proto__, 'setItem');` works with nothing else at all needed, as noted here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6798#issuecomment-440988627

Comment: This also worked for me using sinon

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test localStorage functions then I would like to suggest the [jest-localstorage-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock) npm package.

After configuring this package in your setup test file as per documentation, then you could do this after.

```
test('should save to localStorage', () => {
  const KEY = 'foo',
    VALUE = 'bar';
  dispatch(action.update(KEY, VALUE));
  expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(KEY, VALUE);
  expect(localStorage.__STORE__[KEY]).toBe(VALUE);
  expect(Object.keys(localStorage.__STORE__).length).toBe(1);
});


test('should have cleared the sessionStorage', () => {
  dispatch(action.reset());
  expect(sessionStorage.clear).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(sessionStorage.__STORE__).toEqual({}); // check store values
  expect(sessionStorage.length).toBe(0); // or check length
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To access something that is in the global scope of your module under test, you need to use the `global` namespace. So to access `localStorage` use `global.localStorage`:

```
global.storage = {
  store:{},
  getItem: (key)=>this.store[key],
  setItem: (key, value)=> this.store[key] = value
}
```