# How to resolve local storage not defined in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-jest

when i try to run test cases in vue.js it shows me the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9y4.png) local storage is not defined ,How to resolve this issue please help me to fix this issue.

[Login.spec.js]

```
import  Login from '../../src/Pages/Login.vue';
import{shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
describe('Login.vue',()=>{
    describe('When Loaded',()=>{
        it('has the required elements',()=>{
            const wrapper =shallowMount(Login);
            expect(wrapper.find('#input-username').exists()).toBe(false);
            expect(wrapper.find('#input-password').exists()).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

[axios.js]

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL=process.env.VUE_APP_AXIOS_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer'+ localStorage.getItem('token');

export default class AxiosService{
   postData(url,data){
       return axios.post(url,data).then(response =>{
           return response;
       }).catch(error=>{
           return error;
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest mock localStorage methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883100/jest-mock-localstorage-methods)

Comment: Hello @Matt U ,actually i am not looking this jest mock local storage methods

Comment: You have to mock `localStorage` in your jest tests, because it's a browser API that isn't available by default in your tests.

Comment: @Matt U ,for this any reference available to do these things

Comment: The link in my first comment explains how to mock localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good solution to mock your `localStorage`:
[How do I deal with localStorage in jest tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests)

Basically, there is a store being used to mock the `localStorage`. This way you can set the token based on a fake or real authentication method, which is up to you.